# NewtonSoft Json deserialize decimal numbers with more then 8 decimals

Tags: json.net, decimal, deserialization

I get the following json

```
"location": {
  "x": 3693779.702309093,
  "y": 500061.05750159378
}
```

And the following class

```
Class Location
    public property x as string
    public property y as string
end class
```

I need the json to be deserialised with all decimal positions
But when I deserialise with NewtonSoft Json, it is rounded to 8 decimals only.

Initially I had the class defined with x, y as decimals but I thought the rounding is caused by the data type, that's why I changed to string.

Still, it seems the actual Json deserialization is performed with only 8 decimals.

Any idea how can I make it to deserialize using all decimals?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself.

First I created the convertor below

```
public Class JsonGeometryConverter
  Inherits JsonConverter

  Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
    Return True
  End Function

  Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
    Dim valF As double = reader.Value
    Dim valFS = String.Format("{0:G17}", valF)
    Return valFS
  End Function

  Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then I apply the converter attribute to the properties to extract values to

```
Public Class RestGIS_LocationInfo
  <JsonConverter(GetType(JsonGeometryConverter))>  
  Public Property X As string = ""

  <JsonConverter(GetType(JsonGeometryConverter))>  
  Public Property Y As String = ""
End Class
```

The converter reads the actual value from json data as double, and returns it formatted with up to 17 digits of precision (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx for details)

Comment: There's a problem with this: if the numeric string happens to be an integer, then `reader.Value` will be of type `Int64` or `BigInteger`, not a double.

Comment: In my case, x and y from json are always decimal numbers. But your point is good to be kept on mind, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may have found a bug in Json.NET itself.  When reading a numeric value into a string, the value is first parsed to a numeric type (`double`, `long` or `BigInteger`), then back-converted to a string in [`JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs):

```
                string s;
                if (Value is IFormattable)
                    s = ((IFormattable)Value).ToString(null, Culture);
                else
                    s = Value.ToString();

                SetToken(JsonToken.String, s, false);
                return s;
```

The problem seems to be that [`Double.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not use round-trip precision unless the format string is explicitly specified to be `"G17"`.  If instead I use

```
System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Value).ConvertToString(null, Culture, Value)
```

there is no precision loss.

You might want to [report an issue to NewtonSoft](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about this.

There are a couple of workarounds for this:

1. Deserialize your class with [`JsonSerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatParseHandling.htm).  In this case the numeric value will be temporarily parsed to a `decimal` rather than a `double`.
2. Write a converter that loads the value into a `JValue`, checks for the value being of type `JTokenType.Float`, and returns the correct string:

   ```
   public class StringNumericConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(string);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
               return null;
           var value = JToken.Load(reader);
           if (value.Type == JTokenType.Float)
               return System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(((JValue)value).Value).ConvertToInvariantString(((JValue)value).Value);
           return (string)value;
       }

       public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   Or in VB.NET:

   ```
   Public Class StringNumericConverter
       Inherits JsonConverter
       Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
           Return objectType = GetType(String)
       End Function

       Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
           If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.Null Then
               Return Nothing
           End If
           Dim value = JToken.Load(reader)
           If value.Type = JTokenType.Float Then
               Return System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(DirectCast(value, JValue).Value).ConvertToInvariantString(DirectCast(value, JValue).Value)
           End If
           Return CType(value, String)
       End Function

       Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite() As Boolean
           Get
               Return False
           End Get
       End Property

       Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
           Throw New NotImplementedException()
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

   Note that for integral strings `JValue.Value` will be an `Int64` or a [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); you can't assume it will be a double.

   Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Gh0Ex).

Comment: I've found that out of the workaround you've provided, setting float parse handling to decimal also fixes the issue for me. I'm using version 6.0.5 of Newtonsoft.Json